# How to pass model from partial view to action with a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, model, partial-views

**Context:**

I have an index with a form where a user can select "macros" with a checkbox. These entries are added to a list of class `MacroInfoProperties`, containing a bool that is true if the macro has been selected. This viewmodel is sent to an action where a list of "schematics" is created based off the macros selected. This list of schematics is type `SchematicProperties` and is loaded into a partial view with a form that iterates through and displays each schematic string.

When I submit the partial view's form all the data sent to the next action is seemingly reinitialized; all the data the model had captured in the previous action became things like null and false.

**My Actions:**

```cs
public ActionResult _UpdateCheck(UpdateIndexViewModel updateIndexViewModel)
{
    List<MacroInfoProperties> macrosToUpdate = updateIndexViewModel.MacrosToUpdate;
    List<SchematicProperties> schematicsToUpdate = new List<SchematicProperties>();

    foreach (MacroInfoProperties macro in macrosToUpdate)
    {
        List<SchematicProperties> getSchematics = _dataAccessService.GetSchemsWithMacros(macro.Id);
            foreach (SchematicProperties s in getSchematics)
            {
                //Logic for adding schematics to list
            }
    }
    UpdateIndexViewModel vm = new UpdateIndexViewModel  { SchematicsToUpdate = schematicsToUpdate }; // This is the only property I really need to send to the next action
    return PartialView(vm.SchematicsToUpdate);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContinueUpdate(List<SchematicProperties> schematics)
{
    FunctionGoesHere(schematics)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Initially, I tried passing the same viewmodel from one view to another, and that didn't seem to work. So instead, I turned the partial view's model into a list of only SchematicProperties (since that's all I need to display & pass). The model I'm using in my index is `@model EplanInterface.Core.ViewModels.UpdateIndexViewModel` whereas in my partial view I'm using `@model List<EplanInterface.Core.ViewModels.SchematicProperties>`.

**My partial view:**

```
@model List<EplanInterface.Core.ViewModels.SchematicProperties>


<h2>You will be updating these schematics:</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ContinueUpdate", "Update", Model, FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model == null)
    {
        @: None are selected...z
    }
    else
    {
        if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var s in Model)
            {
                @s.FullPath
                <br />
            }
        }
    }

    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

I find it so weird that I was able to pass the complex type in my Index view with no issues but in the partial view there's an issue. I'm not sure if it's a binding issue or what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I just tried passing a list of strings instead of my complex type, and I stil got null. Seems this issue might not be what I had initially anticipated.  edited the title a bit to hopefully better reflect my issue.